# R - subset - exclude rows based on grepl selection of column value

Tags: r, subset, grepl

I am successfully able to select the items that I don't want.

```
df3 <- subset(df2, grepl("^Imag.*", appt_type))
```

What I am trying to do is create the inverse of that previous command. I want to create a new dataset(`df3`) that consists of all the rows from `df2` except if the `appt_type` value begins with `"Imag"`. I have tried many combinations of [ ] and ! in different places but can't seem to get this right. Been combing the message boards and know I am missing something simple.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `df3 <- subset(df2, !grepl("^Imag.*", appt_type))`?

Comment: If all you want are strings (not) starting with `"Imag"`, you can also remove the `.*`.

Comment: @stefan, that did it! Thank you

Comment: @Rui Barradas Your suggestion did not make any change to the outcome, thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df3 <- subset(df2, !grepl("^Imag.*", appt_type))
```

Basically find all NOT (!) starting with Imag.